# Google Fit implementation - NOT tracking steps when on stand by mode (on Samsung S5, S6) - works on other phones

Tags: android, google-fit

I wrote an app following the Google Fit documentation and the github examples that google has here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit

Using the recording and history api to subscriber, record, retrieve data.

Everything works great. Except when device goes on stand by mode.

When device goes on stand by mode, i can walk a whole bunch of steps. Come back, and Google Fit Api doesn't show any updated steps.

Anybody else have this issue or know how to resolve it? Google Fit not recording steps when device on stand by mode. 
The thing that bugs me most is that the Google Fit app itself (that can be downloaded on play store) shows the correct steps taken even when device was on stand by mode.

Anybody have any idea on what I might be missing.

I even put a wake lock so the device doesn't go to sleep.

Do I need a Service to have Google Fit Track steps when on stand by mode. How does this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.